# How to add bordered triangle over a div tag

Tags: css, html

I have a div tag,

```
 __________
|          |    
|          |    
|          |    
|__________|
```

I want to add a small triangle over it.

```
 _______/\_
|          |    
|          |    
|          |    
|__________|
```

Note: I want my div tag with border of certain color, and div body of another. Say, my div background will be white and border should be blue.
See this please.
http://fiddle.jshell.net/pausP/

Comment: Does it have to have a glow / shadow effect?

Comment: Yes. It should. @Pete i already created div box with triangles, only problem is giving it a border color and shadow.

Comment: @user2207792 have provided an answer for you

Comment: interesting explanations: https://www.sitepoint.com/pure-css3-speech-bubbles/

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Using the initial box with pointer and shadows at http://cssarrowplease.com/ you can restyle them to make the shape you want:

```css
.arrow_box {
  top: 40px;
  position: relative;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #719ECE;  /*set border colour here*/
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 10px rgba(113, 158, 206, 0.8)); /*set shadow colour  and size here*/
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 10px rgba(113, 158, 206, 0.8);
  filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 10px rgba(113, 158, 206, 0.8));
}

.arrow_box:after,
.arrow_box:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.arrow_box:after {
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
  border-width: 19px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -19px;
}

.arrow_box:before {
  border-color: rgba(113, 158, 206, 0);
  border-bottom-color: #719ECE;
  border-width: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow_box">
</div>
```

if you need to move the arrow further right, then just play with the `left` for `.arrow_box:after` and `.arrow_box:before`

Comment: Thanks! i was trying too, but couldn't get the glowing effect on triangles. Now i have it thanks to you!

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21133763/webkit-filter-drop-shadow-for-other-browsers) may help with this if you are wanting the drop shadow in other browsers

Answer (score -2):

You could create the triangle image in a graphics editor then put that image into a DIV and then float that DIV to a fixed coordinate by absolute positioning the DIV and setting the TOP and LEFT coordinates.

Comment: That would be more like patching my code. And incase of excessive zoom i wont be able to display my tag properly, although if its vector(?).

Answer (score -2):

first of all you have to make an image like /\ with that you want a border color and then save that .png image your preferred location then move to css code for positioning that image and so use the  following code:

> background-image:url(images/triangle_img.png);
>   background-repeat:no-repeat;
>   background-position:top;

And adding this code with your specified div styles. and i'm only giving code to place a triangle shape border with division border