# -webkit-filter: drop-shadow for other browsers

Tags: css, drop-shadow

I have a drop shadow effect that I am applying using the following css:

```
-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 10px rgba(113,158,206,0.8));
```

Does anyone know what the equivalent for this is for the other browsers.

Please note I can't use `box-shadow: 0 1px 10px rgba(113,158,206,0.8)` as this won't apply the shadow effect around the css arrow part of the shape

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/meUYt/)

Comment: This is a webkit only property so there isn't an equivalent. Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @donnywals there is an svg filter equivalent for opera and firefox but nothing for ie

Comment: Cross-browser answer is given in this related question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186688/drop-shadow-for-png-image-in-css

Comment: @psdie wow, I searched for ages trying to find an answer like that.  Thanks, please vote to close as duplicate

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Drop shadow for PNG image in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186688/drop-shadow-for-png-image-in-css)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok I have figured this out - the equivalent for opera and firefox is:

```
filter: url(drop-shadow.svg#drop-shadow);
```

where drop-shadow.svg looks like this:

```
<svg height="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <filter id="drop-shadow">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="2.2"/>
    <feOffset dx="1" dy="4" result="offsetblur"/>
    <feFlood flood-color="rgba(0,0,0,0.3)"/>
    <feComposite in2="offsetblur" operator="in"/>
    <feMerge>
      <feMergeNode/>
      <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
    </feMerge>
  </filter>
</svg>
```

IE being so crap doesn't support the svg values feOffset, feFlood or feMerge so doesn't currently have an equivelant

I'll leave this open in-case anyone figures out how to do this effect for IE

**UPDATE**

Thanks to psdie for finding [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186688/drop-shadow-for-png-image-in-css)

IE Version:

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Dropshadow(OffX=0, OffY=1, Color='#444')";
filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Dropshadow(OffX=0, OffY=1, Color='#444')";
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Firefox now supports the non-prefixed dropshadow filter.

Confirmed in FF 43.0.4 on OS X
MDN documentation:
[filter - CSS - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter)