# What CSS method would remove an outline of a div cross browser

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

I have two divs that join together that contain an image. The way the it is layered out the image is in two half's. 
This works as intended but only views correctly in chrome. In the other browsers there is an outline or some layout error which causes the document to look different.
I presumed that outline:0; and border:0; would do the trick.

This is how the image should look. This is taken form chrome. As you can see there is nothing visually wrong with this.

[image: Image form chrome]

Internet Explore [image: Internet Explorer]

FireFox [image: FireFox]

Safari [image: Safari]

CSS:

```
.login{
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-150px;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-200px;
    width:300px;
    height:400px;
    border-radius:10px;
    text-align:center;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:central;
    padding:0 0 0 0;
    border:0;
    border-style:none;
    outline:0;
}
.login header{
    height:75px;
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom:0;
    padding:0 0 0 0;
    border-style:none;
    outline:0;
    border:0;
}
.login header .logo{
    width:150px;
    height:75px;
    outline:none;
    margin-left:75px;
    border:0;
    border-style:none;
    outline:0;
    background:url(assests/logo_tiny.png) center 0px no-repeat;
    background-color:#000;
    border-radius:75px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
    box-shadow:5px 5px 10px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow:5px 5px 10px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow:5px 5px 10px #000;
    -ms-box-shadow:5px 5px 10px #000;
    -o-box-shadow:5px 5px 10px #000;
}
.login form{
    outline:none;
    width:100%;
    height:245px;
    padding:0 0 0 0;
    padding-top:80px;
    border:0;
    border-style:none;
    box-shadow:5px 5px 10px #000;
    background:url(assests/logo_tiny.png) center -75px no-repeat;
    background-color:#000;
    -moz-box-shadow:5px 5px 10px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow:5px 5px 10px #000;
    -ms-box-shadow:5px 5px 10px #000;
    -o-box-shadow:5px 5px 10px #000;
    border-radius:10px;
    font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color:#FFF;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="login">
 <header>
 <div class="logo"></div>
 </header>
 <form>
</form>
</div>
```

**Update**: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mbh6W/1/)

Comment: `div` element doesn't have default outline & border. Try to remove `box-shadow`.

Comment: This works for safari and firefox but internet explore doesn't change at all. Except for the shadow

Comment: I think you are using the wrong type of shadow - instead of a box-shadow on two of your elements, you should use a drop-shadow on your main [login box](http://jsfiddle.net/ML4Rr/1/).  However I don't know how you get the drop shadow to work for ie and you will need to use an svg for firefox - [see this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21133763/webkit-filter-drop-shadow-for-other-browsers)

Comment: I think this is because you have set box-shadow and properties so it is happening. Can you post your code in **fiddle**.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mbh6W/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake by flattening your logo.

It was `150px` wide and only `75px` high. Besides you've removed the `border-radius` at the bottom. On order to have a circle cast a circular shadow the whole div has to be square and the border-radius have to be equal.

See attached fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/mbh6W/2/

So the line you saw was in fact the box shadow of the circle that was flattened at the bottom.

Comment: So instead of splitting the logo just into the two divs, the same affect is achieved by overlapping them. Good answer. Thankyou