# Triangle shadow on CSS ribbon

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I am trying to replicate [image: http://imgur.com/EutshK1] as pixel perfect as I can get and im having trouble trying to do the shadow on the right. Is this possible with css?

CSS:

```
*{margin:0px;padding:0px;}

html {
    width:100%;
        height:100%;
      text-align: center;
    }

.bold {
    font-weight:700;
}

#ribbon {
        padding: .34em 1em;
        margin: 0;
        margin-top: 5%;
        position:relative;
        color: #000;
        text-align: center;
        letter-spacing:0.1em;
        padding-top:12px;
        padding-bottom:12px;
        display: inline-block;
        background: #ffd82b;
        z-index:100;
        box-shadow: 0 7px 0px -2px #ebeced;
    }

#ribbon:after {
        content: "";
        width:3.2em;
        bottom:-.5em;
        position:absolute;
        display:block;
        border: .9em solid #ffd82b;
        box-shadow: 0 7px 0px -2px #ebeced;
        z-index:-2;
    }

#ribbon:after {
        right: -4.3em;
        border-left-width: .75em;
        border-right-color:transparent;
    }

#content:after {
        content:"";
        bottom:-.5em;
        position:absolute;
        display:block;
        border-style:solid;
        border-color: #fc9f42 transparent transparent transparent;
        z-index:-1;
    }
#content:before {
    content:"";
        top:-.5em;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
        position:absolute;
        display:block;
        border-style:solid;
        border-color: #fc9f42 transparent transparent transparent;
        z-index:-1;
}

#content:before {
      left: 0;
      border-width: .5em 0 0 .5em;
    }

#content:after {
      right: 0;
      border-width: .5em .5em 0 0;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="ribbon">
    <span id="content"><span class="bold">Special Offer:</span> Recieve bonus rewards points for signing up</span>
</div>
```

Or here's a jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/k0a6jhv6/

Comment: you may be able to use a [drop-shadow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21133763/webkit-filter-drop-shadow-for-other-browsers) instead of box-shadow. - see right end of ribbon: http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/k0a6jhv6/2/

Comment: Just play around with the rgb colour and opacity to suit your needs: http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/k0a6jhv6/5/

Comment: @Pete brilliant idea. I did not really mess arround too much with these filters by now. http://jsfiddle.net/k0a6jhv6/6/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make this ribbon without using box-shadows, only with borders, z-index and pseudo elements :

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/web-tiki/pen/ByqBVB)**

output :

[image: CSS ribbon]

```css
.ribbon{
  font-size:20px;
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  margin: 2em 1em;
  text-align:center;
}
.text{
  display:inline-block;
  padding:0.5em 1em;
  min-width:20em;
  line-height:1.2em;
  background: #FFD72A;
  position:relative;
}
.ribbon:after,.ribbon:before,
.text:before,.text:after,
.bold:before{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  border-style:solid;
}
.ribbon:before{
  top:0.3em; left:0.2em;
  width:100%; height:100%;
  border:none;
  background:#EBECED;
  z-index:-2;
}
.text:before{
  bottom:100%; left:0;
  border-width: .5em .7em 0 0;
  border-color: transparent #FC9544 transparent transparent;
}
.text:after{
  top:100%; right:0;
  border-width: .5em 2em 0 0;
  border-color: #FC9544 transparent transparent transparent;
}
.ribbon:after, .bold:before{
  top:0.5em;right:-2em;
  border-width: 1.1em 1em 1.1em 3em;
  border-color: #FECC30 transparent #FECC30 #FECC30;
  z-index:-1;
}
.bold:before{
  border-color: #EBECED transparent #EBECED #EBECED;
  top:0.7em;
  right:-2.3em;
}
```

```html
<p class="ribbon">
  <span class="text"><strong class="bold">Special Offer:</strong> Recieve bonus rewards points for signing up</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you add a new element to create missing shadow?

```
#abc {
    display:inline-block;       
    border: .9em solid #ebeced;
    border-right-color:transparent;
    position:absolute;
    right:-73px;
    z-index:-3;
    bottom:-12px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k0a6jhv6/9/

another solution, use span:after inside #content

```
#content span:after {
    content:'';
    display:block;      
    border: .9em solid #ebeced;
    border-right-color:transparent;
    position:absolute;
    right:-73px;
    z-index:-3;
    bottom:-12px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k0a6jhv6/11/