# Weird behavior after transform rotate and border color in firefox

Tags: html, css

I made triangle from square and rotate it so I could use shadows rightly.

But unfortunately I faced with strange spaces inside my triangle in Firefox 48.0.2.

It works perfect in Chrome and IE.

Maybe someone has an expirience with that ? 
Why it does happened ? 
Does anyone know how to fix that ?

Thank you for your answers.

```
.item:after{
position: absolute;
content: "";
border: 39px solid black;
border-color: transparent transparent black black;
box-shadow: -3px 3px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
transform: rotate(-135deg);
left:100px;
top:100px;
}
```

There is an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/uqoh3o9s/11/

[image]

Comment: Have you tried maybe looking at using `fa fa-caret-right` from Font Awesome? - http://fontawesome.io/icon/caret-right/

Comment: Hello @Lee, maybe I will use smth like that, but know I'm just curious about why it does happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you need to rotate it?

```
.item:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 50px 0 50px 86.6px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #000000;
  filter:drop-shadow(0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.5));
  left:100px;
  top:100px;
}
```

Here the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ffnw22ou/1/

Comment: Hello, I wrote it above, sorry for confusing example that I gave.

Comment: I rotate it due to shadow. Try to apply shadow on your example :

Comment: @LezhnevVictor Edited with the shadow

Comment: Thank you, my fault, I also found why it happened, it was due to firefox bug : 

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=818109

Comment: in addition to solution above :

Comment: in addition to solution above: filter:drop-shadow isn't supported by IE, see more : http://caniuse.com/#search=filter%3A

Comment: @LezhnevVictor http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21133763/webkit-filter-drop-shadow-for-other-browsers