# Adding box-shadow to a not-rectangle shaped div (playing with border-radius)

Tags: html, css, border, shadow, box-shadow

Is it possible to add an even shadow to a div that is not a regular rectangle? Adding box-shadow doesn't work the way it works with a normal div. This is the div I'm talking about:

```
#talkbubble {
   width: 120px;
   height: 80px;
   background: red;
   position: relative;
   -moz-border-radius:    10px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
   border-radius:         10px;
}
#talkbubble:before {
   content:"";
   position: absolute;
   right: 100%;
   top: 26px;
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   border-top: 13px solid transparent;
   border-right: 26px solid red;
   border-bottom: 13px solid transparent;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to make a border effect or an actual shadow?

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16237181/how-to-add-bordered-triangle-over-a-div-tag

Comment: I'm trying to make actual shadow effect around the whole div. When I add the box-shadow effect now it makes shadow in a shape of rectangle in the place where there is a triangle made of borders.

Comment: Yes, that would happen. See the linked question. Other than that it's a matter extra pseudo-elements to make the "border/shadow" around the triangle.  An image of the desired result would be ideal if you can provide one.

Comment: Or check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30299093/speech-bubble-with-arrow

Comment: @Paulie_D Thank you for your comment. The image is here: http://prntscr.com/cicbvr In the meanwhile I'll check the provided link. Thanks!
EDIT: I've added the :after with the same attributes but it's still not working.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can. Here is the example:

```css
.circle { 
width:150px;
height:150px; 
border: solid 1px #555;
background-color: #eed; 
box-shadow: 10px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.6); 
-moz-box-shadow: 10px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.6); 
-webkit-box-shadow: 10px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.6); 
-o-box-shadow: 10px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.6); 
border-radius:100px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">

</div>
```