# How to append pseudo content properly

Tags: css

I am hoping to create a box like this:

[image]

using the following CSS rules but I am getting this:

[image]

```css
.box {
  width: 50px;
  color: #303030;
  background: #FFF;
  border: 2px solid #56B665;
  padding: 8px 3px 9px;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box::after {
  content: "";
  border-color: #FFF transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 7px 7px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  width: 1px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.box::before {
  content: "";
  border-color: #56B665 transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 8px 8px;
  width: 1px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="padding:20px">
  <div class="box">100</div>
</div>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47956092/html-css-triangle-with-pseudo-elements/47956145#47956145

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16237181/how-to-add-bordered-triangle-over-a-div-tag

Comment: possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450733/css-triangle-custom-border-color

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is to align both of your triangles (after,before) based on your `.box`.

For this `box` needs to have `position:relative` and your triangles `position:absolute`

Once you cave this, you can align the triangles based on your box position using:

- top
- left
- bottom
- right

For a better understanding, `top:0` and `left:0` will be the top left corner of your box.

Hope this helps :)

```css
.box {
  width: 50px;
  color: #303030;
  background: #FFF;
  border: 2px solid #56B665;
  padding: 8px 3px 9px;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

.box::after {
  content: "";
  border-color: #FFF transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 7px 7px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  width: 1px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: 16px;
}

.box::before {
  content: "";
  border-color: #56B665 transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 8px 8px;
  width: 1px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="padding:20px">
  <div class="box">100</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track.

The main issue is that the before and after should get position absolute, while the parent container, AKA the .box container should have a relative or absolute position.

**NOTE**: After applying the position absolute to the before and after I just mad few minor tweaks to the `before` and `after` to set it up as the image that you have posted

```css
.box {
  width: 50px;
  color: #303030;
  background: #FFF;
  border: 2px solid #56B665;
  padding: 8px 3px 9px;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

.box::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  border-color: #fff transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 6px 6px;
  width: 1px;
  top: -5px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}

.box::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  border-color: #56B665 transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 8px 8px;
  width: 1px;
  top: -8px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="padding:20px">
  <div class="box">100</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think below approach does the trick. You can adjust precise values. `.container` has `:before` pseudo element which is rotated square with borders. `margin-bottom: -3px` moves it, so it sticks to `border-top`, as `rotate(45deg)` messes it's `position: absolute ; bottom: 100%`.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  background: #FFF;
  border: 2px solid #56B665;
}

.container::before {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0) rotate(45deg);
  content: "";
  border-top: 2px solid #56B665;
  border-left: 2px solid #56B665;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  height: 8px;
  width: 8px;
  margin-bottom: -3px;
  display: block;
}

.box {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  color: #303030;
  padding: 8px 3px 9px;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="padding:20px">
  <div class="box">100</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout below code: I also added another variation to achieve the same, which is more cleaner.

```css
.box {
  width: 50px;
  color: #303030;
  position:relative;
  background: #FFF;
  border: 2px solid #56B665;
  padding: 8px 3px 9px;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box::after {
  content: "";
  border-color: #FFF transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 7px 7px;
  margin-top: -39px;
  width: 1px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.box::before {
  content: "";
  top: -16px;
  border-color: #56B665 transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 8px 8px;
  width: 1px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}


.arrow_box {
 position: relative;
 background: #FFF;
 border: 4px solid #56B665;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
.arrow_box:after, .arrow_box:before {
 bottom: 100%;
 left: 50%;
 border: solid transparent;
 content: " ";
 height: 0;
 width: 0;
 position: absolute;
 pointer-events: none;
}

.arrow_box:after {
 border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
 border-bottom-color: #FFF;
 border-width: 30px;
 margin-left: -30px;
}
.arrow_box:before {
 border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
 border-bottom-color: #56B665;
 border-width: 36px;
 margin-left: -36px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="padding:20px">
  <div class="box">100</div>
</div>
<br />


<!-- Another Variation -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="arrow_box">100</div>
</div>
```